# Being asked password twice on git push and failing

Tags: git, bash, authentication, push

When trying to push, I was usually asked for my SSH password once and that would be it, for the past couple of days however git bash began following that up with a another password request which appears to never be correct:

```
$ git push origin branchName
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/luponius/.ssh/id_rsa':
git@x.x.x.x's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
git@x.x.x.x's password:
```

What's going on in this case and how can I get rid of that secondary request?  It was never there before and it's started popping up and stopping me from committing my changes, even though the project appears to still update locally to be all set, on GitLab the changes aren't pushed.

Comment: Is your SSH key up to date? Also on GitHub? Maybe a wrong SSH key format (happened to me once)?

Comment: The remote server is not accepting your public SSH key. You'd have to check with the administrator(s) of the GitLab server to determine the reason. BTW, questions about *configuring* and *using* SSH are off-topic on [so] (as can be seen by hovering over the tag).

Comment: Thanks I'll pursue this with the administration, then.  @AnthonyGeoghegan - should I remove the SSH tag (which is what I did) or should the quesion have been placed elsewhere?  I did not understand the directions.

Comment: If I'd seen your comment earlier, I'd have advised leaving the SSH tag but I wouldn't worry about it too much. You might find the Troubleshooting section of https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/ssh/info (`ssh -vv`) useful for getting more information about the problem.